# Ensure the opening of dialog box

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have an Office add-in. In some pages of the add-in, I need to implement a button which leads to the opening of a Stripe checkout session. As Stripe Checkout is not supported in an iframe, I guess the best choice is to open it in a dialog box.

I tried to use a code similar to follows.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  url,
  { height: 90, width: 60 },
    asyncResult => {
      console.log("asyncResult", asyncResult)
    }
)
```

When we click on the button for the first time, it shows a permission prompt to say the addin wants to display a new window, `Allow` or `Ignore`. Then we click on `Allow`, the session can be opened in a dialog box.

However, after we close the session dialog, and we click on the button again, the permission prompt does not popup, the dialog box does not popup either. In the console, I can see `caught (in promise) Error: Timeout: could not perform cross-storage:get`.

I also tried to add `promptBeforeOpen: false`. With this option, there is no permission prompt, and we can open and close the dialog box many times.

I think in this scenario, the most important thing is to be able to open (and close) the dialog box in all the environments and prevent it from being blocked. Having the permission prompt or not is secondary. So my questions are

1. Without `promptBeforeOpen: false`, why cannot I open the dialog again and how to fix that?
2. With `promptBeforeOpen: false`, can we ensure that the dialog box cannot be blocked?